# create a query that will check the quantity is between a quantity range and output a certain amount base from the product id using jquery in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am working with sale invoice app which has an autocomplete jquery script.

[image]

it autoload the product id which placed in a hidden field. here's my autocomplete script

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 
  if(type =='product_price' )autoType='price'; 
  if(type =='product_cost' )autoType='cost'; 
  if(type =='quantity' )autoType='quantity'; 
  if(type =='product_id' )autoType='id'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchaSaleItems') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },

                success: function(data) {
                  if(!data.length){
                    var notFound = [
                      {
                      label: 'No matches found', 
                      value: response.term
                      }
                    ];
                      response(notFound);
                  } else {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {
                          label: item[autoType],
                          value: item[autoType],
                          data : item
                      }
                    });
                    response(array)
                  }
                }
            });
       },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var data = ui.item.data; 
          var arr = []; 

          id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
          id = id_arr.split("_");
          elementId = id[id.length-1];

          $('.product_code').each(function() {
            arr.push($(this).val());
          });

          // added logic to check if there are duplicates in the array we just populated with product codes, checked against the passed in product code 
          if(arr.includes(data.product_code)) {

            $('#add').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#row'+rowCount+'').addClass('danger');
            // $('#duplicate_entry_'+elementId).text('Duplicate entry. Replace product code to continue. ');
            alert('Duplicate entry. Replace product code to continue. ');
          } else {
            $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#row'+rowCount+'').removeClass('danger');

            $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code).prop('readonly', true);
            $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name).prop('readonly', true);
            $('#product_cost_'+elementId).val(data.cost);
            $('#product_price_'+elementId).val(data.price).prop('min', data.price);
            $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
            $('#quantity_'+elementId).prop('max', data.quantity);
            $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.quantity+' in your stocks');
            $('#price_minimum_'+elementId).text('The minimum price is '+data.price);
          }
        }
   });
});
```

**and here's the query from my controller**

```
public function salesResponse(Request $request){
    $query = $request->get('term','');
    $wh2Summaries=Warehouse2StockSummaries::with('product');

    if($request->type == 'product_code'){
        $wh2Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    $wh2Summaries=$wh2Summaries->get();        
    $data=array();
    foreach ($wh2Summaries as $wh2Summary) {
        $data[]=array(
            'product_code'=>$wh2Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'=>$wh2Summary->product->name,
            'price'=>$wh2Summary->product->selling_price,
            'cost'=>$wh2Summary->product->price,
            'quantity'=>$wh2Summary->qty_in-$wh2Summary->qty_out,
            'id'=>$wh2Summary->product->id
        );
    }

    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return [
            'product_code'=>''
        ];    
}
```

the whole process is working until my boss wants to add another feature which he calls "quantity range" where in a certain range has its own price and that price should dynamically appear in the price field, so let say 1-10 pcs the price is $100, 11-20 the price will be $200 and so on... So I create another table which I called "price ranges" which give a certain product a multiple quantity range

[image]

and I create a relation between products and priceranges

**products model**

```
class Products extends Model
{
    // use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_code',
        'name',
        'categories_id',
        'wh1_limit_warning',
        'wh2_limit_warning',
        'price',
        'selling_price',
        'user_id'
    ];

    // protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function priceRanges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Priceranges', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**priceranges model**

```
class Priceranges extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'priceranges';
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'qty_from',
        'qty_to',
        'amount',
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Products', 'id', 'product_id');
    }    
}
```

from there I don't know what to do next :(

The condition that I want to achieve is, once the user input a quantity, check if the product_id from the hidden field (provided by the autocomplete)
is available in priceranges table, if it is, check which range the quantity is belong then output the amount.

Please can you help me to accomplish this using jQuery? I do not know much about jQuery. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: try this
Products::where('id',13)->priceRanges()->where('qty_from','<=',20)->where('qty_to','>=',20)->get();

Comment: First off, shouldn't your `products()` relationship in `Priceranges` be `$this->belongsTo` rather than `hasMany`?

Comment: Hi @CarlosAfonso the relation works with hasMany

Comment: @Lito even if it works, it doesn't mean it's correct, that's programming by coincidence

Comment: you are correct @CarlosAfonso it should be $this->belongsTo. I updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that I believe you should modify in your Model, is the price in the product table, you should remove it. In this way, all product prices will be in one place: The Priceranges table. So, you can set the default "qty_from" to 0 and the "qty_to" to "nullable ()". If "qty_to" is null, it means that the price is "X" between "qty_from" and infinity.

Changed that, let's go to the Controller.

```
public function salesResponse(Request $request){
    $query = $request->get('term','');
    $wh2Summaries=Warehouse2StockSummaries::with('product');

    if($request->type == 'product_code'){
        $wh2Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    $wh2Summaries=$wh2Summaries->get();        
    $data=array();
    foreach ($wh2Summaries as $wh2Summary) {

        $qty = $wh2Summary->qty_out;

        $price = $wh2Summary->product->priceRanges()
                 ->where('qty_from', '<=', $qty)
                 ->where(function ($q) use($qty){
                     $q->where('qty_to', '>=', $qty)->orWhere('qty_to', null);
                  })->first();
        //in this way, you need every product has their priceRange
        if(isset($price->id)){
            $price = $price->amount; // the price in range chosen 
        }else{ //get the price from original table, if you does not has removed that
            $price = $wh2Summary->product->selling_price;
        }

        $data[]=array(
            'product_code'=>$wh2Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'=>$wh2Summary->product->name,
            'price'=> $price,
            'cost'=>$wh2Summary->product->price,
            'quantity'=>$wh2Summary->qty_in-$wh2Summary->qty_out,
            'id'=>$wh2Summary->product->id
        );
    }

    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return [
            'product_code'=>''
        ];    
}
```

This way, you only need to change the Controller, requiring no changes to your JQuery.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: thanks @HerickC. is there a way we can solve the problem without changing the product table?

Comment: The code I posted has a verification, if a product don't have a `priceRanges`, this will get the `$wh2Summary->product->selling_price` from original table. Change the product table, will be a best practice, this way, the product price always will be in `priceRanges`.

Comment: Hi @HerickC the searching query is not working when I adding the ==>             $qty = $request->input('quantity');

            $price = $wh2Summary->product->priceRanges()
                     ->where('qty_from', '>=', $qty)
                     ->where(function ($q) use($qty){
                         $q->where('qty_to', '<=', $qty)->orWhere('qty_to', null);
                      })->first();

Answer (score 2):

I would add a function in my `Product` model that, given a number, returns the correct price.

```php
public function getCorrectPrice($number) {
    $priceRanges = $this->priceRanges;

    foreach($priceRanges as $range) {
        if ($number >= $range->qty_from && $number < $range->qty_to) {
            return $range->amount;
        }
    }

    return $this->price; // If there is no valid range returns the default producr price

}
```

Now modify your ajax call to include the quantity inserted by the user:

```js
data: {
    term : request.term,
    type : type,
    quantity: quantity, // Get the quantity from the user
},
```

And in your controller:

```
  $quantity = $request->get('quantity');
  $price = $wh2Summary->product->getCorrectPrice($quantity);
```

NOTE: to get better performance, I suggest you to eager load the price ranges with the products:

```
$wh2Summaries=Warehouse2StockSummaries::with('product.priceRanges');
```

Comment: thanks @gbalduzzi! I'll try this now and I will let you know the result.

Comment: Just note that I considered you wanted this behaviour for your field `price`. If you want it for the product field `selling_price`, just change the last return statement in the `getCorrectPrice` function

Comment: hi @gbalduzzi the jquery is not working when I'm adding the "quantity: quantity" inside the data: {},

Comment: also when I'm adding the         $quantity = $request->get('quantity');
        $price = $wh2Summary->product->getCorrectPrice($quantity); in my controller

Comment: You need to get the quantity from the user and put it into a variable called `quantity` before doing `quantity: quantity`.